# Set numeric flag/rank for repetitive values in a column

Tags: sql, teradata

I am working on piece of tracking customer journey on a application.
Trying to set a rank/counter to segregate a session among multiple sessions sharing same id.(Ideally should have been unique).

current structure of table:

[image]

desired output:

[image]

Have tried using row_number over sequence number, but when a sequence_number appears for first time( 4 in case of last row), it takes to be the first count.

How should I go about splitting the data and having a session column whenever the sequence number starts at 1( indicating new session).

Comment: Apologies teradata it is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to want a cumulative count of `'START'`s:

```
select t.*,
       sum(case when activity = 'START' then 1 else 0 end) over
           (partition by session_id
            order by time_stamp
            rows between unbounded preceding and current row
           ) as session
from t;
```

Comment: Thank you @Gordon , works like charm.   just an additional scenario for rows where the time stamp is same eg: the first two rows have same timestamp and hence the code populates session=0 for the 2nd row after populating session=1 for first row, How to deal rows sharing same time_stamp.

Comment: @Tejas . . . Can you ask another question with sample data and explain what you want to happen when there are duplicate times.  Also, it is important to note how often this happens -- after all, if the times are the same on all rows, you need another column entirely to disambiguate the ordering.